# Replacing a set of 2 double quotes in php

Tags: php, string, replace

I have a series of strings that I have read in with fgets() from a .csv file, and then exploded into an array.  The file has the csv standard double quotes.  For example:

```
<a href=""http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HqaemO-lI8s#t=16m6s"" target=_blank"">video</a>
```

is one of the values that I am reading in.  I need all instances of "" to be replaced by just ".  I know that this is a simple solution, but I can't seem to wrap my head around the way that the escape characters would work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use str_replace:

```
$string = '<a href="""">test</a>';
$string = str_replace('""', '"', $string);

echo $string;

// Outputs: <a href="">test</a>
```

Comment: thanks.  That was actually what I had already, and I just realized that it was working fine, and that I was outputting the string BEFORE I formatted it! D'OH!